# First class functions- how are even they possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm struggling with this. I'm reading a book and the example code works really well but I can't get my head around how. The first class functions seem to twist and turn, turn themselves inside out and feed in and out of each other like magic. It goes something like this:

```
   var data = {};
   data["value1"] = fancyMethod.Value1 ;
   data["value2"] = fancyMethod.Value2 ;
   data["value3"] = fancyMethod.Value3 ;

   getGoing( complexFunction , data);

   function getGoing( complexFunction , data){
       function setUpComplexFunction(param1, param2){
       var param3 = param1.someValue ;
       complexFunction(param1, param2, param3, data);
       }

    importantFunction(GetGoing);

    }
```

The thing is the importantFunction() is the one that sets up all the processes that are used to retrieve all the parameters for the functions that feed it.

So all the params are only obtained after the importantFunction() is called. How is it possible that all the other code inside getGoing()  runs OK when when it is unable to obtain its params until importantFunction() is called?

Above is a simplification of the code to just show the concepts I'm struggling with.

Actual code:

importantFunction() is actually http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);

and getGoing() is a function that runs the router and request handlers for the server. Coming from PHP I'm finding it strange that it seems all the requests and urls and request handlers are interpreted before the server even starts.

Source:
https://github.com/manuelkiessling/nodebeginner.org/tree/master/code/application

I guess all this will be obvious to me one day but I wonder if anyone has a simple way of explaining it for now.

Comment: Can you please show us the code of `importantFunction`? It seems to be *important* for your question.

Comment: Btw, *you* are already running the `getGoing` function from the line `getGoing( complexFunction , data);`!

Comment: importantFunction is http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);     getGoing is onRequest(request, response) { ..... router ....}

Comment: @jojojohn Please [edit] your question to clarify your code. (Code typically looks terrible in comments, anyway; it will look much better in your question body.)

Comment: actual code is here https://github.com/manuelkiessling/nodebeginner.org/tree/master/code/application

Answer (score 0):

`importantFunction` (which you haven't included the definition of) will, presumably, call `GetGoing`. At that point it can pass it whatever arguments it likes.

Additionally, the first time `GetGoing` is called, it is called by this line:

> ```
> getGoing( complexFunction , data);
> ```

… which doesn't depend on `importantFunction` at all.